# Retrieve values from multiple vertices in Map with Gremlin Tinkerpop

Tags: java, hashmap, gremlin, tinkerpop

In a graph of several vertices, how can I traverse the graph and collect select properties from multiple vertices?

Let's say I have 4 vertices (Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4), and I want to get the value of a field "name" in Person1, "name" and "age" from Person2, "birthday" from Person3, and "hasPets" in Person4. How can I traverse the graph and collect only the values for each of these fields that I want and store them in a map/hashmap?

From other examples:

[How do I retrieve multiple multi-properties in Gremlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499940/how-do-i-retrieve-multiple-multi-properties-in-gremlin)

[How can I collect property values while traversing a graph with gremlin in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186070/how-can-i-collect-property-values-while-traversing-a-graph-with-gremlin-in-java)

It shows that I can get a map with valueOf(), but I don't see how I can use that on different vertices in one traversal. The other example shows how to get multiple values from different vertices, but they are just stored in a list. I need to be able to know which value is which.

Comment: Will it always be a fairly small set you are searching for? If so using a `choose` step might be appropriate in that case

Comment: What do you mean by "fairly small"? My example was a smaller sized example of what I am actually working on, but I don't think my actual project is a huge set. My current project I need to get fields from 6 different vertices, and a different number of values from each one (total 13 values) (1 field from each of 3 vertices, 2 fields from each of two other vertices, 6 fields from the last vertex). But that is just one traversal. There could be others, but I wouldn't expect them to get much bigger than that.

Comment: You're probably wanting a combination of `.as('p1')`, `.as('p2')`, and `.select('p1', 'p2').by(...).by(...)`.

Comment: By small I meant the number of choices you will be looking at, i.e. just a few people or lots of people. I'll add an answer to see if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have your data, here is a simple example using air routes that shows how a `choose` and an `option` step can be used if you know at least some common property of each vertex you can test on.

```
gremlin> g.V(1,2,3,4).choose(values('code')).
......1>              option('AUS',valueMap('code','city')).
......2>              option('ATL',valueMap('code','region')).
......3>              option('ANC',valueMap('code','desc')) 
  
==>[code:[ATL],region:[US-GA]]
==>[code:[ANC],desc:[Anchorage Ted Stevens]]
==>[code:[AUS],city:[Austin]]
```

If you do not have such a property using the pattern suggested in the other comment along the lines of several `as` and `select` steps will work but might become a bit unwieldy (not that the `choose` case will not as well), at any size.